# How to avoid getting scaled down, translated and rotated?

Tags: pstricks, eps, dvips

The nested input file is used to create an EPS file named `input.eps`. It is generated on the fly via `\immediate\write18`. It just renders some blue concentric circles bounded in a square of side of 6cm.

It is then imported in the outer `pspicture` and enclosed by a red square of side of 6cm.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{filecontents*}{input.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \foreach\i in {0.0,0.2,...,3.0}{\pscircle[linecolor=blue](3,3){\i}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\immediate\write18{latex input}
\immediate\write18{dvips -E -t unknown -o input.eps input}
\newsavebox\myBox
\savebox\myBox{\includegraphics{input}}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \rput(3,3){\usebox\myBox}
    \psframe[linecolor=red](6,6)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

If I compile the above MWE with the following scenarios:

## Scenario 1: (bad result)

```
latex -shell-escape main
dvisvgm -n --bbox=papersize main
```

[image]

## Scenario 2: (bad result)

```
latex -shell-escape main
dvips -t unknown main.dvi
gswin64c -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages#/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o main.pdf main.ps
```

or

```
latex -shell-escape main
dvips -E -t unknown -o main.eps main.dvi
dvisvgm -E -n  main
```

[image]

## Scenario 3: (almost good result)

```
xelatex -shell-escape main
```

[image]

## Question

As you can see in scenario 1 and 2, the *imported* `input.eps` gets scaled down, translated and rotated. How to avoid such unnecessary transformation?

Bonus:  Based on the result of the third scenario, it seems the border of 1cm (that is defined in the nested document class) got ignored. How to preserve this border?

Comment: How do you compile the document. I do not experience any of the issues when I compile with `xelatex -shell-escape`.

Comment: ??? You need to do something like `-shell-escape` at least to get the eps file, right? Why can't you just detail the conversion chain and append it to your question? And the answer to your question in the title is: Use `xelatex -shell-escape`. ;-)

Comment: Why can't you just spell out the conversion chain in detail? And append it to your question?

Comment: Much better, but why am I getting `ERROR: invalid bounding box format 'box=papersize'` when I'm trying the first chain? And what is the `border=1cm` in `input.tex` good for, you're going to crop it when converting to eps and you also seem not to want it because there is no border in the "good solution"?

Comment: If I do that, I get `WARNING: 13 PostScript specials ignored. The resulting SVG might look wrong.` and no pdf. Frankly, I would suggest to make the question more convenient to look at. First of all, you are complaining about the picture getting rotated, but you just draw concentric circles. (It is not yet April 1!) And then pretty much every attempt to confirm the issue results in an error. So I stop here and wish you good luck with this question.

Comment: @marmot: The grid has numbers that we can use as a frame of reference for knowing whether or not the object gets rotated.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity, I get the message `dvips: Can't make it EPSF, sorry`, so that the resulting EPS file is invalid. When converting `main.dvi` with dvips, the resulting PS file looks identical to your scenario 2, i.e. the issue is not directly related to dvisvgm.

Comment: @Martin: the eps is ok!

Comment: @Herbert, the EPS I get contains operator `setpagedevice` that's not allowed according to the EPS specification. If I remove it from the file, I get a transformation similar to that in the above scenario 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
latex <file>
dvisvgm <file>

\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\newsavebox\myBox

\begin{document}

\PSTtoEPS[bbllx=0,bblly=0,bburx=6,bbury=6,
  checkfile=false,headers=all,makeeps=all*]{input.eps}{%    
  \psgrid[gridlabels=0pt](6,6)%
  \pgfforeach\i in {0.0,0.2,...,3.0}{\pscircle[linecolor=blue](3,3){\i}}
}

\savebox\myBox{\includegraphics{input}}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](6,6)
    \rput[lb](0,0){\usebox\myBox}
    \psframe[linecolor=red](6,6)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But where is the border of 1cm in the `input.eps`?

Comment: Then use `bbllx=-1,bblly=-1,bburx=7,bbury=7`